# Monit adding hostname to mailserver and inventing a username

Tags: email, postfix, centos7, monit

I'm brand new to Monit, trying to set it up on my CentOS7 VPS. I put the following settings in `monitrc`:

```
set mailserver 127.0.0.1
set alert me@externaldomain.org
```

But the email fails, and the entry in `maillog` is bizarre:

```
Feb 26 10:47:23 puphpet2 postfix/smtp[11673]: 8B66C18D8: to=<monit@puphpet2.thisdomain.com>, relay=none, delay=2.2, delays=0/0.01/2.1/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=puphpet2.thisdomain.com type=AAAA: Host not found)
```

Of course such a host would not be found - `puphpet2` is just my VPS's hostname, not a subdomain. And there is no `monit` user, let alone a mailbox. What in the world is Monit trying to do?

I tried `set mailserver mail.thisdomain.com`, but I got the same log entry.

If I go local (`set alert me@thisdomain.com`), it works - here is the series of log entries:

```
Feb 26 11:24:33 puphpet2 postfix/smtpd[13965]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 11:24:33 puphpet2 postfix/smtpd[13965]: 65443879: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 11:24:33 puphpet2 postfix/cleanup[13968]: 65443879: message-id=<1519611873.159354611@puphpet2>
Feb 26 11:24:33 puphpet2 postfix/qmgr[14340]: 65443879: from=<monit@puphpet2.thisdomain.com>, size=669, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 26 11:24:33 puphpet2 postfix/smtpd[13965]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 26 11:24:33 puphpet2 postfix/local[13969]: 65443879: to=<me@thisdomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.09, delays=0.05/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Feb 26 11:24:33 puphpet2 postfix/qmgr[14340]: 65443879: removed
```

`monit@puphpet2.thisdomain.com` is a weird sender address, but at least the email gets delivered. But isn't it smarter to send alerts outside the server?

Answer (score 0):

Probably , you didn't set a sender so Monit is building one automatically and the crafted email get rejected by the email server.

```
 set mail-format { from: bofh@foo.bar }

 SET MAILSERVER
    <hostname|ip-address>
    [PORT number]
    [USERNAME string] [PASSWORD string]
    [using SSL [with options {...}]
    [CERTIFICATE CHECKSUM [MD5|SHA1] <hash>],
    ...
    [with TIMEOUT X SECONDS]
    [using HOSTNAME hostname]
```